# Find the function that is implicitly defined in the relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are given a relation $\sqrt{ x^{2} - y^{2}} + \cos^{-1} (\frac{x}{y}) = 0$ and are asked to find a function $g(x)$ that is implicitly defined within it. $y = x$ works but how can I show this is the only function that works and if there are more how can I find them?

Comment: Are you searching for a function $h(x,y)$ or for a function $g(x)$ since your title and your text body are stating different things :)

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed the wording in the question and forgot to change the title accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main branches of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and $\cos^{-1}$ have nonnegative ranges, so their sum is zero only if they are both zero themselves. This forces $y = x$.